# Namespace level enums in c++

Tags: c++, coding-style, enums

Is it a bad practice to have enums in c++ directly at namespace level? I mean not associated with any class? Say if I have an enum and a class that looks something like this,

```
enum Player { USER, COMPUTER}

class Game {
//Logic of the game.
};
```

So should I be declaring the Player enum as a member of game class? Should it be private?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### With C++11

This answer was originally written in 2011. Now that C++11 support is widely available, the preferred way is to use `enum class`, as Matthew D. Scholefield points out below:

```
enum class Player {
    User,
    Computer
};
```

The enumerated constants must be qualified with the name of the enum when referenced (e.g., `Player::Computer`).

#### Before C++11

No, there's nothing inherently wrong with an enum being public. Bear in mind, however, that enumerated constants cannot be qualified with the name of the enclosing enum type. That is, you cannot write `Player::USER` or similar to refer to the `USER` constant; they appear directly in the enclosing namespace. As such, it might be a good idea to set a prefix for your constants so that no name collisions occur.

For instance, consider the following declaration:

```
enum Player {
  PL_USER,
  PL_COMPUTER
}
```

This is safer, because name collisions are much less likely with the "PL_" prefix. Additionally, it improves code readability by hinting at which enum a given constant belongs to.

Languages like C# and Java have adopted a slightly different approach to enums, where one has to specify both the name of the enumeration and the name of the constant, such as `Player.USER`. A similar effect can be achieved in C++ by embedding the enum declaration within a namespace of its own. For example:

```
namespace Player {
  enum Type {
    USER,
    COMPUTER
  }
}
```

This has the effect of embedding `PLAYER` and `COMPUTER` in the `Player` namespace instead of the global (or otherwise enclosing) namespace. Whether this is a good approach or not is, in my opinion, a matter of preference.

Comment: Instead of two-character cryptic prefix, consider e.g. `struct Player { enum Enum{ user, computer }; };`. In a year or two that might be unnecessary as compilers start supporting C++11 features. But until then... Anyway, it's a good idea to reserve **ALL UPPERCASE** for macros. Many people do that.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach I agree. However, I tend to prefer namespaces to structs for enclosing enums, as introducing a namespace doesn't introduce any new types to the system.

Comment: @Martin: I prefer the `struct` precisely because it introduces a type. That's very convenient (e.g. you can inherit from it). A type does not use memory or anything: it's zero cost.

Comment: Note that putting the `enum` in a `namespace` or a `struct` not only puts the names of the constants in the namespace or struct, but also the names of the type.  So if the client code wants to declare a variable of the type, he must write `Player::Type`, and not just `Type`.  If you have C++11, you can use `enum class Type` to put the enum constants into the scope of the enum itself (and inhibit the automatic conversion to `int`).

Answer (score 4):

Generally use minimum scope for anything. That makes it easier to understand things.

However, the clarity or lack thereof due to placement of that `enum` inside or outside a class, is nothing compared to the *shouting*, the use of **ALL UPPERCASE IDENTIFIERS**. Reserve those for macros. In Java they're used for constants because Java got its look and feel from C, where it's not so unusual to define constants as macros (because early C didn't have `const`).

Note that Java does not have a preprocessor, no macros. It's more than a bit silly to take a convention that originated with C, for keeping macros in a separate "namespace", and applying it without understanding to something else so as to be at completely cross purpose with the original intent.

Comment: @kmac: C++ got it's basic syntax directly from C, not just look and feel. And C++ extended it and changed it, in the tradition of C at the time, which was also very much in flux. In early C the creators often used lowercase macro names. You can see vestiges of that in e.g. `assert` and `errno` and so on. The uppercase convention evolved to become dominant as time passed and experience mounted. But it was for the purpose of minimizing name collisions for macros. Java does not have macros, and adopted the convention for its use for defining constants *in C*. That use is irrelevant in C++.

Comment: Uppercase identifiers (SNAKE_CASE) are often used in C++, C, and Java for compile-time constants (including enumerators), to make it clear that their values are not going to change over the lifetime of the program. There is a long history behind this convention, going back to C and POSIX, etc. libraries, and many coding standards encourage it. This usage is still quite common. I disagree with the claims here that uppercase is only for macros. Uppercase enumerators avoid potential collisions with reserved words, most names defined in the C++ standard library, and names of user classes.

Answer (score 2):

If `enum Player` is used ...

- just within `class Game` --> put in **private** scope
- used by `class Game` and its children classes --> put in **protected** scope
- It **relates** to `class Game` and being used at various places --> put
  in **public** scope
- Nowhere related to `Game` --> put in **global / namespace** scope

Answer (score 2):

This is purely a matter of preference; however, I tend to go with Java-like enums in C++:

```
class PlayerType {
  public:
     enum VALUE {USER, COMPUTER};
     explicit PlayerType(VALUE val) : value_(val) {}

     operator VALUE() const { return value_; }
     bool operator==(VALUE other) const { return value_ == other; }
     bool operator!=(VALUE other) const { return value_ != other; }
  private:
     VALUE value_;
     // Copy and assign intentionally allowed.
};
```

The reason I tend to do this is that it is not uncommon to need to add additional functionality (such as conversion to/from string representations) later, and so this structure makes it easy to extend.

Answer (score 1):

If it only is used inside the `Game` class, I would have put the enum inside it.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to define enum within namespace